# Mapsui - how to provide current user's location and focus map on it?

Tags: xamarin, mapsui

I am following the quickstart at https://mapsui.com/documentation/getting-started-xamarin-forms.html and wonder if I need to obtain the location by myself (with e.g Xamarin.Essentials' Location routines) or the Mapsui will obtain one by itself.
I've marked the location priviledges in AndroidManifest, allowed the access but still the blue circle points at 0,0 coordinates.

EDIT: here's the code

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        map = new Mapsui.Map
        {
            CRS = "EPSG:3857",
            Transformation = new MinimalTransformation(),
        };

        var tileLayer = OpenStreetMap.CreateTileLayer();

        map.Layers.Add(tileLayer);
        map.Widgets.Add(new Mapsui.Widgets.ScaleBar.ScaleBarWidget(map) { 
            TextAlignment = Mapsui.Widgets.Alignment.Center, 
            HorizontalAlignment = Mapsui.Widgets.HorizontalAlignment.Left, 
            VerticalAlignment = Mapsui.Widgets.VerticalAlignment.Bottom });

        mapView.MyLocationEnabled = true;
        mapView.PanLock = true;
        mapView.Map = map;
    }
```

Unfortunately, none of `MyLocationEnabled` and `PanLock` make any effect on  the map - the blue circle is stil in 0,0 and the map isn't pan-locked.

Comment: according to the API docs, the MapView control has several properties for "MyLocaton" - http://mapsui.com/api/Mapsui.UI.Forms.MapView.html

Comment: That's interesting as none of those properties seem to work: 
`mapView.MyLocationEnabled = true;
mapView.PanLock = true;`
don't make the map obtain the location nor is pan-locked